# Site wide Tag Cloud

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've created a tag cloud partial view for my site.  The partialview is to be included on all pages on the site.  The data comes from a database.  Is there a way to run the code that lives in the controller globally, so I don't have to put it on every single action of every single controller?

I'd like to avoid putting this on every action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["Tags"] = Tags.GetTags();
    return View();
}
```

and

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(Tags.GetTags());
}
```

It'd be a nightmare if I ever had to change that code.  There has to be a better way of handling database bound content that is on every page of a site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use the `ViewModel` pattern and have a base `ViewModel` class for all your actions:

```cs
public abstract class ViewModelBase
{
    public IEnumerable<Tag> Tags { get; private set; }

    public ViewModelBase()
    {
        Tags = GetTagsFromDatabase();
    }
}
```

Then just make every subsequent `ViewModel` inherit this base class.

```cs
public HomeViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...
}
```

And then in your `Controller` action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ 
    var viewModel = new HomeViewModel();
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: HA!  That's exactly it.  Good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your global code either in your MasterPage, or you also make a custom control out of your code and reuse it in the pages that need that code.